# Check if weekday and time match

Tags: javascript, time

I'm currently looking for a solution to check if weekday is Tuesday to wednesday
so i want to display a message on my website from tuesday 10 pm to wednesday 05 am

How i can build this in a if else sniped?

Comment: Use a library like [moment](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: use http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: Local time or server time?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the user's browser timezone:

```
// get time now
// local to user's timezone
var now = new Date();

// check if it is Tuesday and after 10 --OR-- check if it is Wednesday and before 5
if((now.getDay() == 2 && now.getHours() >= 22) || (now.getDay() == 3 && now.getHours() < 5))
{
    // do yo thing chicken wing
}
```

Comment: It's a serverside node.js query :P but this solve my problem thanks.